# statement about two eigenvector with same eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ are eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$, then so is $c_1 \vec v_1 + c_2 \vec v_2$ when $c_1^2 + c_2^2$ is not zero.

In my book, this statement is true.

But I think this is false.

Because $c_1 \vec v_1 + c_2 \vec v_2$ could be zero vector when $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ are linearly dependent.

So it can't be eigenvectors.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Your observation is right. While the set of vectors with $Av=\lambda v$ is a subspace, the *eigenspace* of $\lambda$, the 0 vector is not counted as *eigenvector*. Clearly, we could have $v_2=-v_1$ and $c_1=c_2=1$ leading to $c_1v_1+c_2v_2=0$, and of course $1^2+1^2\ne 0$ most of the time.

Comment: Well, the statement would be true, if "eigenvectors" is replaced with "linearly independent eigenvectors".